# What could be the better c# design for following requirement?

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns

I am working on creating a c# design for following requirement. I am creating this for a fitness website.

I have an **article** (as Text) and a **exercise** (as Image or Videos) as the base entity. Now i have **workouts**, middle entity, (A workout is basically a set of excercises or articles to be performed in a instructed manner, it will have 2 or more than 2 base entities to make the workout) above these two entities.

Next I have **routines**, top entity, ( A routine is basically two or more workouts taken at a time.) A routine can span for days, weeks, months or year(if provided).

Now i was thinking `composite` design pattern to implement in my application but not sure.

A little peek at database design to help with the c# design.

My database design would look similar to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/226189/designing-a-fitness-weight-lifiting-routine-database) one, check the image in answer.

Also a small example would help me.

I am looking for a design that would be helpful in developing the complex application(eventually it will become one sooner or later.) with ease and also is flexible and scalable.

My application work flow is simple first user adds base entity then the middle entity and then it creates top entity.

Comment: An example of what? Where's the question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You've described a bunch of entities but nothing about what you actually want your application to do (i.e. its *behaviour*).    Think about the behaviour your program needs - that could be in the form of user stories, or a UI mock/drawing with some workflows, or some interaction diagrams, etc.

Comment: I am looking for a design that would be helpful in developing the complex application(eventually it will become one sooner or later.) with ease and also is flexible and scalable. @RubberDuck

Comment: My application work flow is simple first user adds base entity then the middle entity and then it creates top entity.

Answer (score 0):

The **[composite](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html)** design pattern seems at first sight a natural choice, because of the hierarchical structure.  **However**, the goal of the composite pattern, is to handle uniformly the leaves and the components. Furthermore, in a composite, leaves (articles and exercises) can be found at any level of the tree whereas in your structure, they should be at the bottom:

[image]

So, this idea might not be so good after all !  You'd better use a traditional composition model for your limited hierarchy of fixed depth, and homogeneous classes at one level. No need for special structural patterns here.

A pattern that could help you, I believe, is the **[visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)**. It is behavioural and represents operations performed on a complex structure, handling in appropriate manner every type of object that is encountered. THis can be used for saving the structure, to make reports and accumulate values top-down, etc...

Here an [example for composite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185797/Composite-Design-Pattern), in case you'd still want it. 
And here the [visitor example](http://www.dofactory.com/net/visitor-design-pattern)

Comment: I will check the visitor pattern. I would like to know which UML tool you are using - Thanks